# I dont want change vertical-horizontal rate...:) Circle becomes ellipse.... HELP!

Tags: android, android-widget

I want horizontal-vertical rate unchanged. How can ı Do this?? my picture is rate is 320x70.

for example, in my phone(samsung galaxy-s GT-I9000) it looks like 320x100. originally I have a circle but it look ellipse... ı have to fix it, but how can ı do??

its my code.`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/resandroid">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="5"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="3">

<ImageButton android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/menu_mycameras"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_cameras" android:cropToPadding="true">
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton 
    android:paddingTop="20px"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/menu_aboutus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_aboutus" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/menu_help"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_help">
</ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Pls show us the code that draws the circle.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S has a screen resolution of 800 x 480. What are 320x70 and 320x100 numbers that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about your image scaling as fitXY. Just add android:scaleType="sometypehere", and pick a type that suits your needs. Set it to "none" and it won't scale your image at all, where "fitCenter" will scale it to fit proportionally.